# Установка конкретных битов в байте. C#

Tags: c#, .net, byte

Необходимо в байт записывать конкретные биты. Причем данные еще разбиты на 4 кадра. Допустим 1 байт = 8 бит = 4 кадра по 2 бита. Вот установку двух бит мне и необходимо делать в байте каждого кадра.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделать это сдвигами а-ля

```
 inputByte = 0xFF;
 inputByte = (1 << 7) | (1 << 6) | (1 << 5) | (0 << 4) | (1 << 3) | (1 << 2) | (1 << 1) | (0 << 0);
```

Или через enum с атрибутом Flags. Но не знаю как это сделать элегантно.
Что бы например у меня был набор свойств

```
public const byte SetParams = 0x02; // 10
    public const byte ResetParams = 0x01; // 01
```

Я их передавал в метод типо SetByte(byte inputValue, byte command);

и изменял значения во всех 4х кадрах. Например - (01 - 10 - 00 - 10); И на выходе получал измененный байт.

Comment: Установка битов как бы всегда делалась битовым OR с соотв. маской...

Comment: Я понимаю, я не пойму, как это сделать красиво. Не Си стайлом.

Comment: т.е. вот так `int outputBytes = inputByte|SetParams;` вам просто **некрасиво** ?

Comment: Делать это битовым OR это нормально.